# Performance issue because of blocked threads

Tags: multithreading, jms, threadpool, glassfish-3, netty

Since some time we have heavy problems with our web applications running on Glassfish 3.1. The applications communicate asynchroneous through jms. Our native services communicate through JBossNetty.

The problem is that every request to our web applications open a new thread. That is ok but the threads will never be closed. After some hours the system hangs due of the blocked threads.

Some hints why the threads are blocked? I´ve attached the thread dump below.

```
Full Java Thread Dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 21.0-b17 Oracle Corporation

Number of threads: 878

Number of daemon threads: 765

Peak live thread count since the Java virtual machine started or peak was reset: 932

Is support for thread contention monitoring available on this JVM? [true]

Is thread contention monitoring enabled? [false]. If false, some thread synchronization statistics are not be available.

Is support for CPU time measurement for any thread available on this JVM? [true]

Is thread CPU time measurement enabled? [true]. If false, thread execution times are not available for any thread.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "pool-34-thread-851" thread-id: 47.019 thread-state: TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@39e45b53

     at: sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

     at: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 0

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 2

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "pool-34-thread-850" thread-id: 47.018 thread-state: TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@39e45b53

     at: sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

     at: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 0

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 1

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "hz._hzInstance_1_dev.cached.thread-618" thread-id: 47.014 thread-state: TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@3f27c3d6

     at: sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

     at: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 0

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 3

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "New I/O server worker #1-13" thread-id: 47.004 thread-state: BLOCKED Waiting on lock: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@41310d05

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.JBossNettyServer.removeClient(JBossNettyServer.java:412)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.doDisconnect(ServerChannelHandler.java:459)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.channelDisconnected(ServerChannelHandler.java:196)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:132)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:555)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.channelDisconnected(ReplayingDecoder.java:450)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:540)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:360)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:587)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:356)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:281)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:201)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

This thread is blocked waiting on lock owned currently by thread named: pool-66-thread-1, id: 41.339

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 5

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 3

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 31.200.200 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 31.200.200 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "New I/O server worker #1-15" thread-id: 46.997 thread-state: BLOCKED Waiting on lock: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@41310d05

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.JBossNettyServer.removeClient(JBossNettyServer.java:412)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.doDisconnect(ServerChannelHandler.java:459)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.channelDisconnected(ServerChannelHandler.java:196)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:132)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:555)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.channelDisconnected(ReplayingDecoder.java:450)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:540)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:360)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:587)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:356)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:281)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:201)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

This thread is blocked waiting on lock owned currently by thread named: pool-66-thread-1, id: 41.339

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 9

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 2

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 124.800.800 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 124.800.800 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "New I/O server worker #1-22" thread-id: 46.985 thread-state: BLOCKED Waiting on lock: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@41310d05

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.JBossNettyServer.addClient(JBossNettyServer.java:395)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.doIdentify(ServerChannelHandler.java:397)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.messageReceived(ServerChannelHandler.java:283)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:100)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:302)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.unfoldAndfireMessageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:526)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:507)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:444)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:80)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:540)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:274)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:261)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:350)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:281)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:201)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

This thread is blocked waiting on lock owned currently by thread named: pool-66-thread-1, id: 41.339

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 304

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 4

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 156.001.000 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 156.001.000 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "New I/O server worker #1-9" thread-id: 46.938 thread-state: RUNNABLE Running in native

     at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll0(Native Method)

     at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.poll(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:295)

     at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl$SubSelector.access$400(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:277)

     at: sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.doSelect(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:158)

     at: sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:87)

     at: sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.select(SelectorImpl.java:98)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.SelectorUtil.select(SelectorUtil.java:38)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:164)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 308

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 3

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 202.801.300 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 202.801.300 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "New I/O server worker #1-12" thread-id: 46.937 thread-state: BLOCKED Waiting on lock: java.util.Collections$SynchronizedMap@41310d05

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.JBossNettyServer.removeClient(JBossNettyServer.java:412)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.doDisconnect(ServerChannelHandler.java:459)

     at: com.mycompany.library.transmission.jbossNetty.ServerChannelHandler.channelDisconnected(ServerChannelHandler.java:196)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:132)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:754)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.cleanup(ReplayingDecoder.java:555)

     at: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.channelDisconnected(ReplayingDecoder.java:450)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:112)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:545)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:540)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireChannelDisconnected(Channels.java:360)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.close(NioWorker.java:587)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:356)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.processSelectedKeys(NioWorker.java:281)

     at: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:201)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)

     at: org.jboss.netty.util.internal.IoWorkerRunnable.run(IoWorkerRunnable.java:46)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

This thread is blocked waiting on lock owned currently by thread named: pool-66-thread-1, id: 41.339

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 311

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 7

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 156.001.000 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 156.001.000 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "pool-65-thread-267" thread-id: 46.936 thread-state: TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7b4de4b2

     at: sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

     at: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 3

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 2

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "pool-65-thread-266" thread-id: 46.926 thread-state: TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7b4de4b2

     at: sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

     at: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------

Number of times this thread was blocked (to enter/reenter a Monitor): 3

Number of times this thread waited for a notification (i.e. it was in WAITING or TIMED_WAITING state): 3

Total CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

User-level CPU time for this thread: 0 seconds 0 nanoseconds.

Object Monitors currently held or requested by this thread: []

Ownable Synchronizers (e.g. ReentrantLock and ReentrantReadWriteLock) held by this thread: []

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Thread Execution Information:

-----------------------

Thread "pool-65-thread-265" thread-id: 46.920 thread-state: TIMED_WAITING Waiting on lock: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@7b4de4b2

     at: sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)

     at: java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:226)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:460)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:359)

     at: java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:942)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1043)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)

     at: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)

     at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Thread Synchronization Statistics:

-----------------------
```

Comment: About the only real cure is "don't do that". Contrary to your request, creating a thread per request really is *not* Okay.

Comment: I have to agree with @JerryCoffin.  Continually creating, terminating and destroying threads is inefficient, wasteful, slow and prone to errors.  The best way of handling the  termination a thread is to not do it.  Queue requests to a pool of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Sven Moschel,
I am not 100% sure this is your issue, but there are some known bugs with heavy loads and glassfish 3.1.2 http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-18351